# How can i make scrapy to process the url sequentially

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code

```
def parse(self, response):

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="headline_area"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites[:5]:
        item = StackItem()
        log.msg(' LOOP' +str(ivar)+ '', level=log.ERROR)
        item['title'] ="yoo ma"
        request =  Request("blabla",  callback=self.test1)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        page_number = nextlink.split("&")[-1].split("=")[-1]
        if int(page_number) > 500:
           raise CloseSpider('Search Exceeded 500')
        ivar = ivar + 1
        yield request

        mylinks= soup.find_all('a')

        if mylinks:
            nextlink = mylinks[0].get('href')
            page_number = nextlink.split("&")[-3].split("=")[-1]
            request =  Request(urljoin(response.url, nextlink), callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['page'] = page_number
            yield request
```

Now my problem is that suppose i want to stop at `page_number  = 5`

now scrappy goes to that page before the all items from page 1 , page 2 etc are downloaded and stops when it first reaches there.

How can get rid of that porblem that it prcess all links before going to `page = 5`

Answer (score 0):

Does the link has some regularity on different page? For example, if the 5th page's link is `www.xxxx.net/nForum/#!article/Bet/447540?p=5`. You can scrappy link with `p=5` directly.

Comment: yesall are similar wuth p = 1 then 2 and then 5 and so on. can you explain more , how can i do that . Any documentation links

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your issue. You want to process all pages before 5th page, not jump to page 5 directly, right?

If so, I think this issue may be related with the value of `page_number = nextlink.split("&")[-3].split("=")[-1]`. You can print it for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [inline_requests](https://github.com/darkrho/scrapy-inline-requests) decorator.