# Scrapy: Wait for a specific url to be parsed before parsing others

Tags: python, scrapy

**Brief Explanation:**

I have a Scrapy project that takes stock data from Yahoo! Finance. In order for my project to work, I need to ensure that a stock has been around for a desired amount of time. I do this by scraping CAT (Caterpillar Inc. (CAT) -NYSE) first, get the amount of closing prices that there is for that time period, and then ensure that all stocks scraped after that have the same amount of closing prices as CAT, thus ensuring that a stock has been publicly traded for the desired time length.

**The Problem:**

This all works fine and dandy, however my problem is that before scrapy has finished parsing CAT, it begins scraping other stocks and parsing them. This results in an error, as before I can get the desired amount of closing prices from CAT, scrapy is trying to decide if any other stock has the same amount of closing prices as CAT, which does not exist yet.

**The actual question**

*How can I force scrapy to finish parsing one url before beginning others*

**I have also tried:**

```
def start_requests(self):
    global start_time
    yield Request('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT', self.parse)
    # Waits 4 seconds to allow CAT to finish crawling
    if time.time() - start_time > 0.2:
        for i in self.other_urls:
            yield Request(i, self.parse)
```

but the stocks in `other_urls` never commence, because scrapy never goes back to `def start_requests` to check if the time is above `0.2`

**The Entire Code:**

```
  from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from sharpeparser.gen_settings import *
from decimal import Decimal
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from sharpeparser.items import SharpeparserItem
import numpy
import time

if data_intervals == "m":
    required_amount_of_returns = 24
elif data_intervals == "w":
    required_amount_of_returns = 100
else: 
    required_amount_of_returns = 

counter = 1 
start_time = time.time()


class DnotSpider(Spider):

# ---- >>> ENSURE YOU INDENT 1 ---- >>>
# =======================================
name = "dnot"
allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com", "http://eoddata.com/", "ca.finance.yahoo.com"]
start_urls = ['http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT']
other_urls = ['http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/Z.htm'
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/Z.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/Z.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/0.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/1.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/2.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/3.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/6.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/8.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/0.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/1.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/2.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/3.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/4.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/5.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/6.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/7.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/8.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/9.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/A.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/Z.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/A.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/Z.htm',
    'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=A', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=B', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=C', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=D', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=E', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=F', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=G', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=H', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=I', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=J', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=K', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=L', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=M', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=N', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=O', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=P', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=Q', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=R', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=S', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=T', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=U', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=V', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=W', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=X', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=Y', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=Z',
    'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=0', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=1', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=2', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=3',
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=A', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=B', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=C', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=D', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=E', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=F', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=G', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=H', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=I', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=J', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=K', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=L', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=M', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=N', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=O', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=P', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=Q', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=R', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=S', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=T', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=U', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=V', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=W', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=X', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=Y', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=Z',
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=A', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=B', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=C', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=D', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=E', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=F', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=G', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=H', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=I', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=J', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=K', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=L', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=M', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=N', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=O', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=P', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=Q', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=R', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=S', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=T', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=U', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=V', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=W', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=X', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=Y', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=Z',
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=A', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=B', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=C', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=D', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=E', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=F', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=G', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=H', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=I', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=J', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=K', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=L', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=M', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=N', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=O', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=P', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=Q', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=R', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=S', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=T', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=U', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=V', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=W', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=X', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=Y', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=Z']

def start_requests(self):
    global start_time
    yield Request('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT', self.parse)
    # Waits 4 seconds to allow CAT to finish crawling
    if time.time() - start_time > 0.2:
        for i in self.other_urls:
            yield Request(i, self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    if "eoddata" in response.url:
        companyList = response.xpath('//tr[@class="ro"]/td/a/text()').extract()
        for company in companyList:
            if "TSX" in response.url:
                go = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={0}.TO&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g={7}'.format(company, beginning_month, beginning_day, beginning_year, ending_month, ending_day, ending_year, data_intervals)
                yield Request(go, self.stocks1)
            elif "LSE" in response.url:
                go = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={0}.L&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g={7}'.format(company, beginning_month, beginning_day, beginning_year, ending_month, ending_day, ending_year, data_intervals)
                yield Request(go, self.stocks1)
            elif "HKEX" in response.url:
                go = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={0}.HK&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g={7}'.format(company, beginning_month, beginning_day, beginning_year, ending_month, ending_day, ending_year, data_intervals)
                yield Request(go, self.stocks1)
            elif "AMS" in response.url:
                go = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={0}.AS&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g={7}'.format(company, beginning_month, beginning_day, beginning_year, ending_month, ending_day, ending_year, data_intervals)
                yield Request(go, self.stocks1)
            else:
                go = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={0}&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g={7}'.format(company, beginning_month, beginning_day, beginning_year, ending_month, ending_day, ending_year, data_intervals)
                yield Request(go, self.stocks1)
    elif "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT" in response.url:
        go = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=CAT&a={0}&b={1}&c={2}&d={3}&e={4}&f={5}&g={6}'.format(beginning_month, beginning_day, beginning_year, ending_month, ending_day, ending_year, data_intervals)
        yield Request(go, self.stocks1)
    else: 
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_tableout1"]//table/tr')[1:]
        for row in rows:
            company = row.xpath('.//td[1]/b/a/text()').extract()
            go = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={0}&a={1}&b={2}&c={3}&d={4}&e={5}&f={6}&g={7}'.format(company, beginning_day, beginning_month, beginning_year, ending_day, ending_month, ending_year, data_intervals)
            yield Request(go, self.stocks1)

def stocks1(self, response):

    current_page = response.url
    print current_page
    # If the link is not the same as the first page, ie. stocks1 is requested through stocks2, get the stock data from stocks2
    if initial_ending not in current_page[-iel:]:
        returns_pages = response.meta.get('returns_pages')
        # Remove the last stock price from the stock list, because it is the same as the first on the new list
        if not not returns_pages:
            if len(returns_pages) > 2:
                returns_pages = returns_pages[:-1]
    else:
        # Else, if the link does match that of the first page, create a new list becuase one does not exist yet
        returns_pages = []

    # This grabs the stock data from the page
    rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//table/tr')[1:]
    print "stocks1"
    print returns_pages
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        try:
            values = cells[-1]
            try:
                float(values)
                # And adds it to returns_pages
                returns_pages.append(values)
            except ValueError:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            continue  
    print "after"
    print returns_pages 

    # exp determines if there is a 'Next page' or not
    exp = response.xpath('//td[@align="right"]/a[@rel="next"]').extract()
    # If there is a 'Next Page':
    if not not exp: 
        # And this is the first page:
        if initial_ending in current_page[-iel:]:
            #create necessary url for the 2nd page
            next_page = current_page + "&z=66&y=66"
        # If this is not the first page
        else:
            # This increases the end of the link by 66, thereby getting the next 66 results on for pages 2 and after
            u = int(current_page[-6:].split("=",1)[1])
            o = len(str(u))
            u += 66 
            next_page = current_page[:-o] + str(u)
            print next_page, "66&y in curr_page"
        # Then go back to self.stocks1 to get more data on the next page
        yield Request(next_page, self.stocks2, meta={'returns_pages': returns_pages}, dont_filter=True)
    # Else, if there is no 'Next Link'
    else: 
        # Send the retuns to finalize.stock to be saved in the item
        yield Request(current_page, callback=self.finalize_stock, meta={'returns_pages': returns_pages}, dont_filter=True)

def stocks2(self, response):

    # Prints the link of the current url
    current_page = response.url
    print current_page

    # Gets the returns from the previous page
    returns_pages = response.meta.get('returns_pages')
    # Removes the last return from the previous page because it will be a duplicate
    returns_pages = returns_pages[:-1]
    print "stocks2"
    print returns_pages
    # Gets all of the returns on the page
    rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//table/tr')[1:]
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()
        try:
            values = cells[-1]
            try:
                float(values)
                # And adds it to the previous returns
                returns_pages.append(values)
            except ValueError:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            continue  

    print "after 2"
    print returns_pages

    # exp determines if there is a 'Next page' or not
    exp = response.xpath('//td[@align="right"]/a[@rel="next"]').extract() 
    # If there is a 'Next Page':
    if not not exp:
        # And somehow, this is the first page (should never be true)
        if initial_ending in current_page[-iel:]:
            # Add necessary link to go to the second page
            next_page = current_page + "&z=66&y=66"
            print next_page, "66&y not in curr_page"
        # Else, this is not the first page (should always be true)
        else:
            # add 66 to the last number on the preceeding link in order to access the second or later pages
            u = int(current_page[-6:].split("=",1)[1])
            o = len(str(u))
            u += 66 
            next_page = current_page[:-o] + str(u)
            print next_page, "66&y in curr_page"
        # go back to self.stocks1 to get more data on the next page
        yield Request(next_page, self.stocks1, meta={'returns_pages': returns_pages}, dont_filter=True) 
    else: 
        # If there is no "Next" link, send the retuns to finalize.stock to be saved in the item
        yield Request(current_page, callback=self.finalize_stock, meta={'returns_pages': returns_pages}, dont_filter=True) 
        print "sending to finalize stock"

def finalize_stock(self,response):

    current_page = response.url
    print "====================="
    print "finalize_stock called"
    print current_page
    print "====================="
    unformatted_returns = response.meta.get('returns_pages')
    returns = [float(i) for i in unformatted_returns]
    global required_amount_of_returns, counter
    if counter == 1 and "CAT" in response.url:
        required_amount_of_returns = len(returns)
    elif required_amount_of_returns == 0:
        raise CloseSpider("'Error with initiating required amount of returns'")

    counter += 1
    print counter

    # Iterator to calculate Rate of return 
    # ====================================
    if data_intervals == "m": 
        k = 12
    elif data_intervals == "w":
        k = 4
    else: 
        k = 30

    sub_returns_amount = required_amount_of_returns - k
    sub_returns = returns[:sub_returns_amount]
    rate_of_return = []
    RFR = 0.03

    # Make sure list is exact length, otherwise rate_of_return will be inaccurate
    # Returns has not been checked by pipeline yet, so small lists will be in the variable

    if len(returns) > required_amount_of_returns:
        for number in sub_returns:
            numerator = number - returns[k]
            rate = numerator/returns[k]
            if rate == '': 
                rate = 0
            rate_of_return.append(rate)
            k += 1

    item = SharpeparserItem()
    items = []
    item['url'] = response.url
    item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/h2/text()').extract()
    item['avg_returns'] = numpy.average(rate_of_return)
    item['var_returns'] = numpy.cov(rate_of_return)
    item['sd_returns'] = numpy.std(rate_of_return)
    item['returns'] = unformatted_returns
    item['rate_of_returns'] = rate_of_return
    item['exchange'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="rtq_exch"]/text()').extract()
    item['ind_sharpe'] = ((numpy.average(rate_of_return) - RFR) / numpy.std(rate_of_return))
    items.append(item)
    yield item
```

Comment: your line: `for i in self.other_urls:` has a renegade indent. Could you also put it either a) in class structure or b) in separated function form so anyone helping out can just paste into their editor and debug?

Comment: your class indenting is still sketchy as well as at the top of the code snippet

Comment: @alexmcf for whatever reason stack doesn't let me paste the whole thing into one code block... And it would take forever to manually space everything from line 25 to 250 with spacebar...

Comment: don't need anything below the `parse()` function as it's just the iteration through urls that is the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Actual Question

As for the actual problem of doing each request in sequence... There are a few questions similar to yours:

- [crawling sites one-by-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297011/crawl-a-list-of-sites-one-by-one-with-scrapy)
- [crawling urls in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566322/scrapy-crawl-urls-in-order)
- [processing urls sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150955/how-can-i-make-scrapy-to-process-the-url-sequentially)

As a general summary there seem to be a couple of options:

1. Utilise the `priority` flag in a `start_requests()` function to iterate through websites in a particular order
2. Set [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=1`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) to ensure that only one request is carried out at a time
3. If you want to parse all sites all at once after the first `CAT` ticker has been done. It might be possible to specify an `if` function to flick the above setting to a higher value if you have already parsed the first site using the [settings API](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#topics-api-settings)

#### General Coding

I can't run your exact code because you are missing the class structure but I can already see a few things that might be tripping you up:

1. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/4013571) describes `yield`. to better understand how your `yield` function is working run the following:

   ```
   def it():
       yield range(2)
       yield range(10)

   g = it()
   for i in g:
       print i
   # now the generator has been consumed.
   for i in g:
       print i
   ```
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701249/scrapy-whats-the-correct-way-to-use-start-requests) SO post also demonstrates that the `start_requests()` function overrides the list specified by `start_urls`. It appears that for this reason your urls in `start_urls` are overridden by this function which only ever yields a generator expression of `Request('http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT', self.parse)`
3. Is there any particular reason that you are not listing all the urls in the list `start_urls` in the order you want them parsed and delete the function `start_requests()`? The [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_urls) on `start_urls` state:

   > subsequent URLs will be generated successively from data contained in the start URLs
4. Sticking things in `globals` will tend to cause you problems in projects like this, it's usually better to initiate them as attributes of `self` in a `def __init__(self):` function which will be called when the class is called.
5. This might be petty but you could save yourself a lot of scrolling / effort by listing all the symbols in a separate file and then just load them up in your code. As it stands you have a lot of repetition in that list that you could cut out and make it far easier to read.

Comment: 1) That makes sense, mostly... however all url's are actually run in `start_requests()` without using a time restriction. 2) I had to override `start_urls` in order to ensure that CAT was scraped first. 3) I initially had them all in `start_urls`, however scrapy doesn't scrape the items in there based on their location in the list. The small hack that I did works great at ensuring CAT goes first. 4) Thanks, I'm new at python and figuring out how to pass variables around is definitely one of my weaknesses

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. I just realized too that it won't work unless you build the actual scrapy project. Unfortunatly I can't accept this as the awnser as it doesn't tell me how to wait for the url. However, I appreciate it nevertheless!

Comment: There, that should help

Comment: Before when I had all of the urls in `start_urls` sometimes CAT would be scraped first, sometimes it wouldn't.  Anyways, this updated awnser is awesome!

Comment: thanks, I've edited the comments about `yield` so that they are clearer too as it is a complex concept to understand for someone new to python

Comment: Wow! That yield example did a great job explaining it for me. Thanks!!